# Whatsapp web security

Tags: encryption, whatsapp, end-to-end-encryption

If I use WhatsApp Web on a computer at work that is connected through a proxy, is there a possibility that they will intercept my messages?

I know that, thanks to the proxy, they can see the pages that I visit, but they could also spy on WhatsApp conversations?

Answer (score 5):

No.  Whatsapp, Signal, and other secure messaging systems use end-to-end encryption.  You can read more about the underlying algorithm here: 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Ratchet_Algorithm.

That being said, if you are using a work computer which your employer controls, your employer may be able to read your messages on your local machine before your messages are sent and encrypted/after they are received and decrypted.

Comment: thanks,How could he read my messages on my local machine?

Comment: Many different ways.  If they install VNC or some similar screen sharing application, they can simple read the messages as you are reading them.  Your messages also exist in memory outside in a unencrypted state in order to show you the messages, so theoretically they could read the clear text messages straight from memory as well.

Comment: thanks, very much :)....

Could some virus have access to the browser's temporary data (chrome), and get from there the information of the chats?
and if the pc is in a shared network?

Comment: @Majes7ik, that's a different set of questions (and would be duplicates on this site)... Short answers for people who don't need to understand the details are: **Yes**, a virus may be able to read any other program's memory. **No**, someone else on your network can not read end-to-end encrypted traffic.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short.

Whatsapp encrypts every outbound communication send to their servers, if you are in a corporate environment all of your requests are being intercepted and forwarded depending on the security layers that are present at the company.

Your PC -- Proxy Server --- ( Some checks if you are requesting anything malicious ) -- if corrected forward it to the internet -- if not return denied access.

Even if they intercept your sent requests they are encrypted and virtually impossible to decrypt.

To wrap things up:

- Will they know you are using whatsapp web ? YES
- Will they be able to intercept Whatsapp requests ? YES
- Will they know what are you sending ? NO

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Will they know what are you sending ? NO <- Your employer may be able to read your messages on your local machine. As stated in @user52472 answer

Comment: How could he read my messages on my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on your computer.

Let's say the proxy used by your company is a standard, regular proxy... then, it probably don't touch HTTPS and you're OK (at least regarding exchanges, but as said previously, your company sysadmin will still be able to see that you're using whatsapp).

On the worst case, your company could have deployed a more agressive proxy and deployed associated certificate authority on your computer.
In this setup, when you attempt to connect to whatsapp page, then the proxy:

1. Generate on-the-fly a SSL certificate matching the targetted host (in this case web.whatsapp.com).
2. Sign (still on the fly) the resulting certificate with its embedded certificate authority (the same deployed on your computer)
3. Intercept **all** the traffic, even if your browser reports you a safe connection.

Since the certificate looks legitime (*CommonName* matching server FQDN), and has been signed by a trusted authority, then your computer will trust it...

The only way to ensure this is to compare the certificate fingerprint for:

- The certificate you get when connecting from work.
- The certificate you get when connecting from another, direct connection.

Nevertheless, keep in mind that, as previously said, whatsapp use end-to-end encryption so even with the most malicious proxy, your company won't be able to retrieve your messages... at least using a proxy.

As previously said, other ways exist: hidden VNC service, or any malware-like tools would do the job.

Comment: How can I tell if I have hidden vnc?... I did a scan and found an adware helper, that could allow you to read whatsapp web chats? thanks very much !!! :)

Comment: @Majes7ik The easiest way to tell if you have a hidden VNC is to ask your IT department.  The safest is to assume that, if it's a work computer, then it isn't your computer, and you shouldn't do whatever you want with it.